# Reference not found in VBA for Excel Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to call a python script via an Excel Macro. However I do not see a reference to Excel Python in VBA References. I have PyWin32 installed and I also have Excel Python installed.

Comment: In the past I did this by calling the python script in a bat file that I ran from vba. I don't have the code pieces anymore, but you can surely google it. (the bat file may have opened a vbsscript that in turn ran the python script).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much interaction between Excel and Python you're going to need, it could also pay off to try out the `xlwings` package. This package is built on top of `pywin32`. It allows you to call a Python script from VBA, and subsequently the Python script can easily exchange data with the Excel application by means of `xlwings` functions. See these [examples](https://www.xlwings.org/examples) and the [documentation](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: Which is better, excel python https://github.com/ericremoreynolds/excelpython, or xlwings?

Comment: @jenkelblankel `xlwings` is a successor to `excelpython`. As the `excelpython`'s github page notes: "ExcelPython has been integrated into xlwings! Going forwards ExcelPython will be no longer be actively maintained and any further development work will take place within the context of xlwings."

Answer (score 1):

*.py files are usually executed by a python.exe program(the one installed with PyWin32). If the python.exe program is included in the environment variable PATH(like it normally should be after the installation), this means you can call the execution of the *.py files from anywhere using a commandpromt by calling "python filename.py" in the command shell.

So from your vba code you should be using the Microsoft Scripting Runtime or Windows Script Host library and call a shell in a similar manner as below

```
Call Shell("python filename.py")
```

If the python.exe is not included in the environment variable PATH, this means you must call the long path of the program likeso

```
Call Shell("c:/path/to/python.exe filename.py")
```

Notice the space inbetween the executable and the python filename to be executed.